# Is there any way function to count the number of table tags using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrap through Wikipedia website and display the tables, but the table number will be specified by the user.

So I thinking, get the number of table tags from the page, loop through and display the number specified by the user and display the table.

So far I am only able to display the contents of the table.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
from lxml.html import fromstring


import re

wiki = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Test_cricket_records"

header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'} #Needed to prevent 403 error on Wikipedia

req = urllib2.Request(wiki,headers=header)

page = urllib2.urlopen(req)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page)



table = soup.findAll("table")


for row in table :

    td=row.findAll("tr")

    for data in td :

        cells = data.findAll("td")
```

---

is there a better way. Please guide me.

Comment: You already have all (50) tables in the list you named `table`. In your first for-loop you are iterating over these tables (so it might be better to type `for table_tag in table:` rather than `for row in table:`. So what is the problem then?

Comment: Yes. It runs but i was looking for a way to get the number of table as specified by the user.                                                                                                     Naming it as table_tag is a good idea.   Thank you.

Comment: Maria, (after your own solution - which got removed) you are getting the error`AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'find_all'` because you are attempting to iterate over a `bs4.element.Tag`. There is no longer a need for `for row in table` because you have after typing `table = soup.findAll("table")[2]` exactly one table. Simply remove the outer for-loop.

Comment: I found a function that does the needful.                                                     table = soup.findAll("table")[2]

Comment: Thank you Oliver. I realized my mistake and removed the solution and traceback error.                                                                                       Appreciate your timely responses.